# I want to find all possible combinations of a group of 6 out of 13 total options.

Tags: permutations, combinations

I am trying to find all possible class combinations for a group of six, where only one group member can be a part of one class (think Dungeons and Dragons classes). Example:
Player 1: Can be any of 13 classes
Player 2: Any remaining class minus players 1 choice
Player 3: Any remaining class minus players 1-2 choices
Player 4: Any remaining class minus players 1-3 choices
Player 5: Any remaining classes minus players 1-4 choices
Player 6: Any remaining classes minus players 1-5 choices

Is there an existing formula? I keep getting directed to permutations but I'd like to have all possible group combinations if possible.

Comment: You have exactly the right idea.  Your answer can be expressed as $6! \cdot \binom{13}{6}$ because there are $\binom{13}{6}$ ways to choose the group of $6$ classes and then, once those have been selected, there are $6!$ ways to assign players to classes.

Comment: @RobertShore Thank you! Do you know a way to visually represent those results/combinations? Whether that's through excel, word doc etc.?

Comment: That gets more into a programming question than a math question.  It could be done with nested for loops, or using a package written by someone else like using Itertools in python.  If you wanted to do it by hand, the process is the same as writing down numbers... increase the number at the end repeatedly until you can't at which point increase the one before it and reset the last number to the lowest available, if you have to then go back even further (like how 2999+1 = 3000).  The only real difference is here you don't want repeats and you are using "classes" rather than digits.

Comment: "*Do you know a way to visually represent those*"  Before going through the effort... you really should ask yourself... *why?*  You know what each entry would look like.  You know how many entries there would be in such a list.  You know *how* to write such a list.  You know how to randomly select an item from the list.  What good is it to actually spend the effort to produce that list?  What benefit does it bring to have a physical complete copy of the list rather than just having a theoretical potential copy that you never fully created?  It does not seem useful to me in the slightest.

Comment: @JMoravitz Honestly I just wanted an easier way to come up with t-shirt designs instead of creating the 1560 variations manually. But the help here has been validating to my thought process!